# WebRTC between clients in different networks

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I used WebRTC video conference using two Chrome tab (which means I call myself). Everything worked well.

I used WebRTC video conference with two different laptop as well,
 if those laptop were on the same network. I used my office's network behind proxy.

However, WebRTC video conference didn't work if I used it with one laptop on Office Network, and the other on Personal Home network.

this is live example for This code from scaledrone with channel code 
**sX5nWDp8dfyEysqh** 
[Live example](https://vps.nemra-1.com/webrtc/)
repo from here
[repo](https://github.com/herkyl) 
And this is The code

```js
// Generate random room name if needed
if (!location.hash) {
  location.hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}
const roomHash = location.hash.substring(1);

// TODO: Replace with your own channel ID
const drone = new ScaleDrone('sX5nWDp8dfyEysqh');
// Room name needs to be prefixed with 'observable-'
const roomName = 'observable-' + roomHash;
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
   urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};

let room;
let pc;


function onSuccess() {};
function onError(error) {
  console.error(error);
};

drone.on('open', error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  room = drone.subscribe(roomName);
  room.on('open', error => {
    if (error) {
      onError(error);
    }
  });
  // We're connected to the room and received an array of 'members'
  // connected to the room (including us). Signaling server is ready.
  room.on('members', members => {
    console.log('MEMBERS', members);
    // If we are the second user to connect to the room we will be creating the offer
    const isOfferer = members.length === 2;
    startWebRTC(isOfferer);
  });
});

// Send signaling data via Scaledrone
function sendMessage(message) {
  drone.publish({
    room: roomName,
    message
  });
}

function startWebRTC(isOfferer) {
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

  // 'onicecandidate' notifies us whenever an ICE agent needs to deliver a
  // message to the other peer through the signaling server
  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({'candidate': event.candidate});
    }
  };

  // If user is offerer let the 'negotiationneeded' event create the offer
  if (isOfferer) {
    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      pc.createOffer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
    }
  }

  // When a remote stream arrives display it in the #remoteVideo element
  pc.onaddstream = event => {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  }).then(stream => {
    // Display your local video in #localVideo element
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // Add your stream to be sent to the conneting peer
    pc.addStream(stream);
  }, onError);

  // Listen to signaling data from Scaledrone
  room.on('data', (message, client) => {
    // Message was sent by us
    if (client.id === drone.clientId) {
      return;
    }

    if (message.sdp) {
      // This is called after receiving an offer or answer from another peer
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), () => {
        // When receiving an offer lets answer it
        if (pc.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {
          pc.createAnswer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
        }
      }, onError);
    } else if (message.candidate) {
      // Add the new ICE candidate to our connections remote description
      pc.addIceCandidate(
        new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate), onSuccess, onError
      );
    }
  });
}

function localDescCreated(desc) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(
    desc,
    () => sendMessage({'sdp': pc.localDescription}),
    onError
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.scaledrone.com/scaledrone.min.js'></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #0098ff;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 0 50px;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
    }
    video {
      background: white;
      background-image: url(https://www.kirupa.com/images/orange_logo_svg.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: contain;
      max-width: calc(50% - 5%);
      margin: 0 5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .copy {
      position: fixed;
      top: 25px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      font-size: 18px;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="copy">Send your URL to a friend to start a video call</div>
  <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
  <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, for that purpose you need STUN servers, which help in *some* number of cases. You have one public STUN server, whether this one does its job nobody really knows. It's a good idea to add more than one and to choose some commercial servers if you want some real assurance. Secondly, for cases where even STUN doesn't help, you need some TURN servers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need a STUN server (which you are using in your `iceServers` configuration) and both network needs to allow UDP traffic. In my experience, office networks occasionally block UDP traffic on certain port ranges (e.g., everything but DNS).

To test WebRTC with a client known to work try the [AppRTC video chat client](https://appr.tc)  from [WebRTC Samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/). If this doesn't work, you should check the UDP rules on your office firewall; otherwise you will need a TURN server.

Comment: thank you so much..i will try to  get my own turn server today

Answer (score 0):

It will work if your connection is secured https not http